# Can trademark attorneys advertise in UK?

Tags: copyright, intellectual-property, trademark, patents

In some countries, it's illegal for trademark and patent attorneys to advertise.
Is it also the case in the UK?

Comment: "In some countries . . . " which ones? I'm not aware of any countries with a total ban even though many countries regulate this. Even a telephone directory listing, building directory lobby sign, or firm website is to some extent an advertisement.

Answer (score 2):

The  Patent  Regulation  Board  of  the  Chartered  Institute  of  Patent  Attorneys  and  the  Trade Mark Regulation Board of the Institute of Trade Mark Attorneys working jointly together as the **Intellectual Property Regulation Board** (IPReg) have the following rule in their Code of Conduct:

Rule 18 –  Publicity
Publicity  and  promotional  activity  of  any  kind  by  regulated  persons  is  permitted  if  it  is  fair,  honest, accurate and is not misleading and is not otherwise in breach of these Rules.

https://ipreg.org.uk/wp-content/files/2018/12/Rules-of-Conduct-December-2018.pdf

There is additional Guidance in that file.

IPReg is the independent regulatory body for the trade mark attorney and patent attorney professions in the UK.